How many times has a Starfleet group or individual attempted a coup of the Federation government?
In DS9 (S4/E12), "Paradise Lost," a Starfleet Admiral attempts to overthrow the civilian Federation government and implement a military dictatorship. How many times (in canon) has a Starfleet group or individual attempted a coup of the Federation government?

What are you considering "canon" for Star Trek? Are you just looking at films/TV series?  There are vast numbers of "official" novels out there that are wildly inconsistent and contradictory, at least one of which ("Dreadnought") involves an attempted coup.

I'm not familiar with the books. I'm a fan of TOS, STNG, DS9 and Voyager; and I've seen the first five films. I don't really know what is and isn't canon. So that's why I specified canon — because (a) I don't know and (b) I'm interested in learning from those far more knowledgeable than myself (which is probably 99% of this group). ;)
